# Python: Mock ImportError with pytest.fixture

Tags: python-3.x, patch, python-mock

I'm trying to make tests on a helper function that reacts on import success or not.

The success test is working but not the failing one, do you know why ?

The helper :
homeassistant/components/owntracks/helper.py

```py
"""Helper for OwnTracks."""
try:
    import nacl
except ImportError:
    nacl = None

import logging

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def supports_encryption() -> bool:
    """Test if we support encryption."""
    _LOGGER.info(nacl)
    return nacl is not None
```

My test :
tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py

```py
"""Test the owntracks helper."""
from unittest.mock import patch
import pytest
import logging

from homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper import supports_encryption

_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

@pytest.fixture(name="nacl_imported")
def mock_nacl_imported():
    """Mock a successful import."""
    with patch("homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper.nacl"):
        yield


@pytest.fixture(name="nacl_not_imported")
def mock_nacl_not_imported():
    """Mock non successful import."""
    with patch("homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper.nacl") as mock_import:
        mock_import.return_value = ImportError()
        yield mock_import


def test_supports_encryption(nacl_imported):
    """Test if env supports encryption."""
    _LOGGER.info(supports_encryption())
    assert supports_encryption()


def test_supports_encryption_failed(nacl_not_imported):
    """Test if env does not support encryption."""
    _LOGGER.info(supports_encryption())
    assert not supports_encryption()
```

Also tried:

```py
    with patch("homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper.nacl", return_value=None):
        yield

AND

    with patch("homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper.nacl", side_effect=ImportError()):
        yield
```

Test logs :

```
 py.test tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py
Test session starts (platform: linux, Python 3.7.4, pytest 5.2.2, pytest-sugar 0.9.2)
rootdir: /home/quentin.pollet@sglk.local/Documents/home-assistant, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: timeout-1.3.3, cov-2.8.1, requests-mock-1.7.0, aiohttp-0.3.0, sugar-0.9.2
collecting ... 
 tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py ✓                                       50% █████     

―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――― test_supports_encryption_failed ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

nacl_not_imported = <MagicMock name='nacl' id='139733318227280'>

    def test_supports_encryption_failed(nacl_not_imported):
        """Test if env does not support encryption."""
        _LOGGER.info(supports_encryption())
>       assert not supports_encryption()
E       assert not True
E        +  where True = supports_encryption()

tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py:34: AssertionError
------------------------------------- Captured stderr call --------------------------------------
INFO:homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper:<MagicMock name='nacl' id='139733318227280'>
INFO:tests.components.owntracks.test_helper:True
INFO:homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper:<MagicMock name='nacl' id='139733318227280'>
--------------------------------------- Captured log call ---------------------------------------
INFO     homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper:helper.py:14 <MagicMock name='nacl' id='139733318227280'>
INFO     tests.components.owntracks.test_helper:test_helper.py:33 True
INFO     homeassistant.components.owntracks.helper:helper.py:14 <MagicMock name='nacl' id='139733318227280'>

 tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py ⨯                                      100% ██████████

Results (0.15s):
       1 passed
       1 failed
         - tests/components/owntracks/test_helper.py:31 test_supports_encryption_failed
```

I'm new at Python, but motivated, be nice ;)

Answer (score 0):

From your given details, it is cleared that the method **`supports_encryption`**() will check the import status of nacl. If not installed, then it would change the **nacl** value to False. Moreover, after that, you are verifying the value of nacl with True/False (nacl is not None will return True, if it is not None).

The return value of **`supports_encryption`**() will always be True.

In test method test_supports_encryption_failed(), you used assert not **`supports_encryption`**(), that's why it is failing.

For mocking the imports value, use the below:-

```
$ pytest -vsx test_11.py
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.15+, pytest-4.6.6, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.13.0 -- /usr/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
metadata: {'Python': '2.7.15+', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.15.0-60-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic', 'Packages': {'py': '1.8.0', 'pytest': '4.6.6', 'pluggy': '0.13.0'}, 'Plugins': {u'html': u'1.22.0', u'metadata': u'1.8.0'}}
rootdir: /home/nikhilesh
plugins: html-1.22.0, metadata-1.8.0
collected 2 items                                                                                                                                                      

test_11.py::test_success ('Value is ', <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>)
PASSED
test_11.py::test_fail ('Value is ', None)
PASSED

======================================================================= 2 passed in 0.07 seconds =======================================================================
$ cat test_11.py 
import utility
import mock



def test_success():
    print("Value is ", utility.os)



@mock.patch("utility.os", return_value = None)
def test_fail(mock_os):
    print("Value is ", utility.os.return_value)
```

Comment: Hi !
Thanks for your answer :)

But if I can correct the value of `nacl` will turn to None, not False ?

I don't get why using `not supports_encryption()` is making my test fail.
I should use `supports_encryption() == False` ?  I think it's the same.

Also, my goal is to test `supports_encryption()`, not the value of `nacl`.

I will also test using `@mock.patch` instead of `@pytest.fixture`.